# how to compare all values for each row in a dataframe in python

Tags: python, dataframe, max, row

Good morning guys,
my problem is simple:

Given a dataframe like this:

```
import pandas as pd 
  
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'a': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
                    'b': [8, 18, 27, 20, 33, 49],
                    'c': [2, 24, 6, 16, 20, 52]})
print(df)
```

I would like to retrieve for each row the maximum value and compare it with all the others. If the difference is >10, create another column with a string 'yes' or 'not'

```
   a   b   c
0  1   8   2
1  2  18  24
2  3  27   6
3  4  20  16
4  5  33  20
5  6  49  52
```

I expect this result:

```
   a   b   c  res
0  1   8   2  not
1  2  18  24  not
2  3  27   6  yes
3  4  20  16  not
4  5  33  20  yes
5  6  49  52  not
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: how do you calculate **difference** ? What is all the others ? All values or current row's values ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess, the below code can help:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({ 'a': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
                    'b': [8, 18, 27, 20, 33, 49],
                    'c': [2, 24, 6, 16, 20, 52]})

def find(x):
    if x > 10:
        return "yes"
    else:
        return "not"

df["diff"] = df.max(axis=1) - df.apply(lambda row: row.nlargest(2).values[-1],axis=1)
df["res"] = df["diff"].apply(find)
df.drop(columns="diff", axis=0, inplace=True)
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: doesn't he wants to compare all? Why are you comparing just to the second largest only?

Comment: @Waqar if the if the difference between the largest and the second largest is 10... that indicates that there is no number between the largest and second largest right?

Comment: What I see from his "res" column in the results table, he wants to compare the maximum value with all other values, and wants to put "yes" if the maximum value is larger by at least 10 than every other value in the row. So, if the maximum value is larger than the second largest value in the row by 10, then it will be larger than all remaining values in the row by a margin of more than 10.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.

Around twice to ten times as fast as other answers provided here

import pandas as pd

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
                   'b': [8, 18, 27, 20, 33, 49],
                   'c': [2, 24, 6, 16, 20, 52]})

df["res"] = df.apply(lambda row: "yes" if all(row.apply(lambda val: max(row) - val > 10 or val == max(row))) else "not", axis=1)

print(df)
```

results

```
   a   b   c  res
0  1   8   2  not
1  2  18  24  not
2  3  27   6  yes
3  4  20  16  not
4  5  33  20  yes
5  6  49  52  not
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'a': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
                    'b': [8, 18, 27, 20, 33, 49],
                    'c': [2, 24, 6, 16, 20, 52]})

def _max(row):
    first, second = row.nlargest(2)
    if first - second > 10:
        return True
    else:
        return False

df["res"] = df.apply(_max, axis=1)
```